# Passing a Session.Item to a MySQL query

Tags: asp.net

I have a aspx web page that has a session variable:

```
Dim UserName As String = CType(Session.Item("UserName"), String)
```

I am attempting to include this variable in the `MySQL` query of a `SqldataSource` for a Databound `GridView` control:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT DeviceDescription, DeviceType, DeviceID 
   FROM validate WHERE ClientID='" & UserName & "'"
```

However, this does not work.

How do you pass/include this `session` variable in the `DataSource` of the `GridView`?

Comment: What is the value of Username if you put a breakpoint on it. What is the value of SQL when you pu a breakpoint on it.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Can you fill up _"does not work"_ with content? Currently your question is not answerable since you have omitted the relevant parts.

Comment: @DanielA.White Everyone assumes that dynamic sql is vulnerable. What if the Session variable that contains username has been sanitisied. What if this is a completely closed system. While I appreciate it may not be good coding, your comment may well not be accurate.

Comment: @ChrisBint Are you serious? Why to leave hole somewhere in "sanitization" when you can have one secured way via parametrized query? Daniel's comment is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, completely serious. You have no idea of the context of this code and while I agree that parameterized queries are the better solution, it does not make this vulnerable.